# Failed to convert any image file to a jpeg one using FFMPEG

Tags: react-native, image-processing, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert any image that is selected to a jpeg file, but my command keeps saying at least one output must be specified, this is the ffmpeg command

```
const selectImage = async () => {
const result = await launchImageLibrary({
      mediaType: 'photo',
      selectionLimit: 1,
    });
const tempPath = RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath + 'uri.jpeg';
if (result.didCancel || result.assets.length === 0) return;
try {
    FFmpegKit.executeAsync(
        '-i ' + result.assets[0].uri + ' -c:v ' + tempPath
      )
```

I've look into many of the documentation with react native but i can't find a specific one in regards of converting only images, nor the packages specify it since the multimedia options given as packages are audio or video.

Comment: Update

        '-i ' + result.assets[0].uri + ' output.' + tempPath

[swscaler @ 0x7feb2a767000] [swscaler @ 0x7feb2a774000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly

[image2 @ 0x7feb4261a570] The specified filename 'output./Users/alejandrooyuelabolanos/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/43B05948-C290-461B-B8F2-DC754E8BD022/data/Containers/Data/Application/58D07278-288B-4766-B7B7-AF2DA0B7686B/tmp/uri.jpg' does not contain an image sequence pattern or a pattern is invalid.

could not open file 
conversion failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue you're having is that `-c:v` doesn't have a parameter attached to it and instead thinks your output file is the encoder you're trying to use.

Either remove the `-c:v` option entirely, or run `ffmpeg -encoders` and choose one from the list (eg: `-c:v libx264`)

Comment: I'm no longer using -c:v this is my new command '-i ' + result.assets[0].uri + ' output.' + tempPath

But it says that the temptah does not contain an image sequence pattern or is an invalid one

Comment: Here is the full segment of code



const selectImage = async () => {
    const result = await launchImageLibrary({
      mediaType: 'photo',
      selectionLimit: 1,
    });
    const tempPath = RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath + 'uri.jpg';
    if (result.didCancel || result.assets.length === 0) return;
    try {
      FFmpegKit.executeAsync(
        '-i ' + result.assets[0].uri + ' output.' + tempPath
      )

Comment: get rid of ' output.'

Comment: I did it before, but it just takes the 2 paths as one and does nothing, one of the commands I tried was the following one '-i ' + result.assets[0].uri + tempPath

Comment: there still needs to be a space between the arguments. You want the command to look like this
`ffmpeg -i whatever.jpg /Users/alejandrooyuelabolanos/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/43B05948-C290-461B-B8F2-DC754E8BD022/data/Containers/Data/Application/58D07278-288B-4766-B7B7-AF2DA0B7686B/tmp/uri.jpg`

Comment: I understand that, but since in react native the ffmpeg command needs to go inside of a string which is why i have the '-i ' + file to concatenate them, if i just put a space between the 2 variables that contain the paths it will throw an error, that's why i put a + between them, should I just add a string with a blank space between the variables?

Comment: this seems more like a javascript question than an ffmpeg question now lol
String interpolation is my favorite way to do this

FFmpegKit.executeAsync(
  \`-i ${result.assets[0].uri} ${tempPath}\`
)